# What is the point of the stub functions in lodash?

Tags: ecmascript-6, lodash, anonymous-function

Could someone tell me what is the use case of?

```
_.stubArray
_.stubFalse
_.stubObject
_.stubString
_.stubTrue
```

Why not just do...

```
() => []
() => false
() => ({})
() => ''
() => true
```

I mean half of them are shorter as is, they're all shorter if you remove the spaces padding the `=>`. Would it ever be advisable to use these lodash functions in code?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

There is no point. On older browsers without lambdas, they'd take slightly more space... [here is the source](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.13.1/lodash.js#L15303)

```
function stubArray() { return [] }
function stubFalse() { return false }
function stubObject() { return {} }
function stubString() { return '' }
function stubTrue() { return true }
```

Now they're just a waste of space and more things to read about in the lodash docs.

Comment: Downvoted because there is an actual point to them. In some cases it is useful to have a single instance of a function that returns a static value instead of creating anonymous functions. That can be quite expensive in a loop or when dealing with many objects. "Shorter" does not always mean better.

Answer (score 4):

**Just one use case:** Lambdas create a new different function every time they are run, so when used in react render functions, they can create unnecessary re-renders. Lodash stubbs don't have this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use case: Rather than creating functions with the same return multiple times, you can use a single instance of one.